# PHP Explode method in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem here

is there a way to explode things up in `sql` query and make a group by after it  ?
actually i want use exactly php explode-like function in a sql query, is there a way to do that ?

`test{explode}test2{explode}test2{explode}test3{explode}test{explode}test`

return :

```
test  `count 3`

test2 `count 2`

test3 `count 1`
```

here's a sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b318d/1

Comment: What does the string look like before?

Comment: Before when @Anthony? i want something like `mysqli_query($sqli,'SELECT * FROM test WHERE explode("{explode}",value) GROUP BY explodedResult');`

Comment: So if I'm reading right, you are storing values as a comma delimited string? That's bad.

Comment: And also what does `WHERE explode("{explode}",value)` mean? What is it comparing it to?

Answer (score 2):

you can make your own function and then use it in query

here is an example by Federico Cargnelutti http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

For example

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(`field_name`, ',', 0) 
FROM TEST
GROUP BY SPLIT_STR(`field_name`, ',', 0)
```

Comment: What is it means : `This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled ` i tried to put the function in PHPMYADMIN Sql query and get that.

Comment: you can read more about it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html. you need to execute this query `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` before creating function to avoid that error

Comment: i did that, i created the function and lunched the query you gave. still not workin

Comment: are you getting error or you are not satisfied with the result?